# UIViewController as a popup in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

In the current project,I am using an UIViewController with 2 text Fields and a text area.

Text fields are used as drop-down (custom logic) and based on drop-down selection information is displayed in text area for e.g. State and city are two drop down. On click of State drop down city data is populated in second drop down and on selection of city corresponding info is fetch and displayed in Text-area.

I have a requirement to move this logic to custom popup. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this with minimal changes in Xamarin iOS.

[image: Original UI View Controller]

Comment: provide some screenshoots how it's supposed to look like

Comment: The attached UI View Controller should be displayed on parent page as popup with semi transparent background or as Slideupmenu.

Answer (score 0):

It would use `UIPopoverController` in this care. You already have a view controller with all the UI elements. You can use it as the `DetailViewController` so you don't have to change that much. Only it's size and the background. You can use it for both iPhones and iPads.

Here you have a sample project with source code:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/Popovers/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new UIViewcontroller in the storyboard, set the background colour of the main view to transparent, then create another view on top of that and put in any controls you want to display etc. then in the UIViewcontrollers init method add in the following:

```
    public OverlayView(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext;
    }
```

That way the background view that you've set as transparent won't just show black, it'll show in the context of the screen that called it, then you just present it as you would any other view, and add in some dismiss action events if you want it to pass data back etc. Hope this helps.